# Issue using Git Bash on Windows Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, windows, oh-my-zsh

Few months ago I installed zsh on git bash (Git for Windows), then I installed oh-my-zsh and Windows Terminal and everything was working fine. Recently, when I open windows terminal, I get an error that I can't figure out and then fix. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Error opening Windows Terminal:

```
(anon):15: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
/c/Users/myUsername/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh:32: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
/c/Users/myUsername/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:67: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
/c/Users/myUsername/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:68: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
compinit:539: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
/c/Users/myUsername/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:35: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
/c/Users/myUsername/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:43: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted
```

My Windows Terminal configuration:

```
{
   "commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe -i -l",
   "cursorShape": "filledBox",
   "fontFace": "MesloLGL NF",
   "fontSize": 12,
   "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
   "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
   "name": "Bash",
   "padding": "8",
   "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
   "snapOnInput": true
}
```

My `.bash_profile`:

```
# Launch Zsh
if [ -t 1 ]; then
    exec zsh
fi
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there a reason you aren't using WSL? Git Bash shell is a bit of a hack and not Linux or Unix. The things that go wrong are happening on the Windows side, so you need to think of what changes you made to Windows.

Comment: Hi @Aron T, before I used to use Git Bash because of WSL2 slowness. After somewhile I've understood that the slowness was due to the fact I used WSL2 with my project (Angular) inside Windows disk partition. Now, I use WSL2 with the project inside WSL partition and it's working very well. Thanks :)